# How to override emacs-projectile default configuration for project?

Tags: c++, cmake, emacs, emacs-projectile

I try to use emacs with projectile to configure and than build C++ CMake project. By default projectile use next configuration:

```lisp
(defconst projectile--cmake-manual-command-alist
  '((:configure-command . "cmake -S . -B build")
    (:compile-command . "cmake --build build")
    (:test-command . "cmake --build build --target test")))
```

How can I override this settings for my project(only for my project)? Suppose I want to make something like:

```lisp
(defconst projectile--cmake-manual-command-alist
  '((:configure-command . "cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -S . -B .build")
    (:compile-command . "cmake --build .build")
    (:test-command . "cmake --build .build --target unit-tests")))
```

I search throw [documentation](https://docs.projectile.mx/projectile/projects.html) but can't find some simple solution. I expect to see modification for `.dir-locals.el` file with some new variables. Maybe am I doing something completely wrong and I should use it in different way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried put this `.dir-locals.el` in the root dir of your project?

```lisp
;;; Directory Local Variables
;;; For more information see (info "(emacs) Directory Variables")

((c++-mode . ((projectile--cmake-manual-command-alist . ((:configure-command . "cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -S . -B .build")
                                                    (:compile-command . "cmake --build .build")
                                                    (:test-command . "cmake --build .build --target unit-tests"))))))
```